# Markdown not rendering properly with Jekyll (although I suspect CSS is the culprit)

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

The CTF team I'm in has a GitHub Pages website powered by Jekyll, but the markdown rich text isn't rendering. I suspect that CSS is the problem, not Jekyll or the markdown renderer, but I'm not sure where the problem is.

Site: http://ctftoolkit.com/

Blog post: http://www.ctftoolkit.com/tutorial/2015/12/12/swift.html

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/ID10T-Errors/ID10T-Errors.github.io

Comment: It's seems to be working now. Did you confirm ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `{{page.content}}`, use `{{content}}`.

For some reason, `page.content` doesn't render the Markdown, however `content` does.

Comment: Thank you! Of all the answers, this buried answer is actually the only correct one :/